# Where can i find the effective and deeper tutorial for Javascript (client side controller) in lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

where can i see best tutorials and further explanation on Javascript (client side controller) in lightning mobile app development. Please help me i am very new in lightning and in salesforce.

Comment: If you are looking for help with javascript in general (not related to salesforce or lightning), Douglas Crockford knows what he's talking about. David Flanagan wrote a good book too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete Trailhead module for [lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components). Including your client side controller and many other things. There is also a very good example which you can also check [here.](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2015/03/13/tutorial-building-lightning-components-with-spring-15/)